# c++ boost combine crc checksum

Tags: c++, boost, crc

I have one directional graph where for every item I compute the a crc represents its own data + the data of the items it points too.

To avoid recomputing the data of one item multiple times I would like to use already computed crc for the items. Or in pseudo code:

```
crc = process_data(data);

for (auto item : items)
    crc = combine_magic(crc, item.crc());
```

The question is what combine_magic should be. I use boost crc library, but I did not find such function there. Simply using xor is a bad idea, because I might finish of some items pointed even number of times - which will eliminate them from the equation. Zlib seems to offer such function https://github.com/madler/zlib/blob/master/crc32.c, but I would like to avoid adding one more dependency.

Comment: It looks like you could call ``process_bytes()`` at every node in your graph. If you need to branch then you could perhaps make a copy of the crc object before visiting the next node.

Comment: @moof2k Thank you, This is an option I thought about too - but I give up on it, because it seems a bit too expensive for the goal - and hard on parallel computing since it will require a single crc object to go through all the items.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use zlib, then just copy the code from zlib: `crc32_combine_()`, `gf2_matrix_square()`, and `gf2_matrix_times()`. It's about 60 lines of code.

Your `combine_magic()` function also needs the number of bytes in the item used to compute the CRC in order to combine it with `crc`. So save that length along with the CRC.

By the way, boost requires zlib anyway.